# Конфигурация logback + spring boot без .xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, логирование

Можно ли прикрутить и если можно, то как, logback к spring boot без использования .xml ?

Comment: Поподробнее можно о том, где именно Вас xml не устраивает...в dependencies? в application context?  Обойтись можно и там и там без него.

Comment: Вообще , что бы в проекте отсутствовали xml. По logback не нашёл как настраивать без  , везде примеры только с использованием конфигурации в xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
     <version>2.3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Вот пример файла logback.groovy

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder
import ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender

import static ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.DEBUG
import static ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.INFO

appender("STDOUT", ConsoleAppender) {
  encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
    pattern = "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} Groovy - %msg%n"
  }
}

logger("com.example.beans", INFO)
root(DEBUG, ["STDOUT"])
```

Не забываем конфиг для java машины:

```
-DLogback.configurationFile=logback.groovy
```

Подробно в официальной документации [тут](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html)

Comment: Спасибо за пример. А без использования groovy можно ли ? с groovy знаком только по наслышке .

Comment: Можно, но только уже с использованием другого логгера. Например, log4j

Comment: Всего, в logback я знаю 2 метода конфига: .xml и .groovy.  Других методов конфигурации, разработчики этого логгера не сделали. Так что, раз уж такая аллергия на .xml, придется выбрать другой логгер.
В принципе, все видно в официальных доках. А там я больше способов не видел.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ)